# How can I inspect form data being Posted?

Tags: reverse-engineering, sniffing, postdata

I am reverse engineering an app and I need to see what is in the post data without viewing the form source. Is a there a decent app/plugin to see what is being posted?

I'm looking for something other then packet sniffing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) in conjunction with Firefox.

Comment: This is really a bad answer and does not deserve to be accepted. The question is **How** to do so, not what tool to use for it.

Comment: How do you use Firebug to inspect form data being posted? I would like to know how to do this, but you did not answer the question.

Comment: After installing firebug, go to the webpage you want to "reverse engineer". 

Press F12 to start firebug, look for the console tab (if I remember it had to be enabled first). Enable also the "persistent" option, so it doesn't clear after every page. 

When you do the post from the web page, everything will be registered, and you expand the entries to see the requests and responses.

Comment: The question was precisely what tool to use.. op said `Is a there a decent app/plugin`

Answer (score 10):

Also for Firefox, there are plugins named [HTTPfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) and [Tamperdata](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) that allow you to do more with POST data then firebug. I personally have all three on my work computer.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler for Internet explorer.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it.  It should work for any web browser.  Just set the proxy info.  Chrome picks up the proxy setting automatically, just like IE does.

Answer (score 3):

Charles - web debugging proxy app

[go to website](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/getting-started/)

Answer (score -10):

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

Comment: Because it is completely unhelpful and non applicable to the situation.